# function returns a pending Promise instead of a boolean

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, async-await

I have this two functions , and I expect that `alreadyInGame` returns a boolean, but returns a Pending promise , why if Its an `async` function if I'm using `await` on the asynchronous code

```
lobby = async function(req,res){
    var game_id = req.params.game_id;
    var game =  await Game.findById(game_id);
    //console.log('already', !alreadyInGame(req.user._id, game_id, game.users));
    var exists = alreadyInGame(req.user._id, game_id, game.users); 
    if( !exists){
        console.log('already');
        game.users.push({
            user: req.user,
            calification: 0
        });
        game.save();
    }

    res.render('game/lobby.twig', { 
        username: req.user.username 
    });
}

async function alreadyInGame(user_id, game_id ,users){
    var result = await Game.findById(game_id).find({ 
        users: { 
           $elemMatch: { user: user_id } 
        }
    }); 
    
    return result.length != 0;
}
```

Comment: Being an `async` function means that it *does* return a promise, because it does asynchronous stuff. Using `await` doesn't make anything synchronous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`alreadyInGame` is an `asycn` function, you need to `await` on it:

```
var exists = await alreadyInGame(req.user._id, game_id, game.users);
```